# Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String

Tags: json, ajax, extjs

I have facing problems with EXT js code to store data using Java.
Below is my code. Can one please help me.

Below is my NewCustomersVerify.js code:

```
var myHit = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    fields:['Id','Name'],
    data:[
        {Id:'0',Name:'No'},
        {Id:'1',Name:'Yes'}
    ]
});
var myRisk = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    fields:['Id','Name'],
    data:[
        {Id:'0',Name:'Low'},
        {Id:'1',Name:'High'}
    ]
});

Ext.define('Test.test.web.test.view.test.NewCustomersVerify', {
     "xtype": "newCustomersVerify",
     "items": [{
          "xtype": "panel",
          "items": [{
               "xtype": "panel",
               "items": [{
                   "xtype": "displayfield",
                   "fieldLabel": "Name :",
                   "margin": 5,
                   "value": "TEXT",
                   "name": "customerName",
                   "title": "Customer Name",
                   "itemId": "lnajnbi",     "bind": "{customerName}"
              },{
                  "xtype": "displayfield",
                  "fieldLabel": "Nationality :",
                  "margin": 5,
                  "value": "TEXT",
                  "name": "nationality",
                  "title": "Nationality",
                  "itemId": "lnbjnbi",     "bind": "{nationality}"
             },{
                 "xtype": "displayfield",
                 "fieldLabel": "UniqueId No :",
                 "margin": 5,
                 "value": "TEXT",
                 "name": "uniqueIdNo",
                 "title": "UniqueId No",
                 "itemId": "lncjnbi",     "bind": "{uniqueIdNo}"
            },{
                    "xtype": "hiddenfield",
                    "fieldLabel": "HiddenText",
                    "bindable": "contactId",
                    "margin": 5,
                    "name": "contactId",
                    "title": "HiddenText",
                    "itemId": "oidgafi",
                    "bind": "{contactId}"
               },{
                   "xtype": "hiddenfield",
                   "fieldLabel": "HiddenText",
                   "bindable": "screeningId",
                   "margin": 5,
                   "name": "screeningId",
                   "title": "HiddenText",
                   "itemId": "didgafi",
                   "bind": "{screeningId}"
              }],
               "layout": "vbox",
               "autoScroll": true,
               "margin": 5,
               "columnWidth": 0.5,
               "itemId": "cieadni",
               "dockedItems": []
          }, {
              "xtype": "panel",
              "items": [
              {
               "xtype": "combo",
               "fieldLabel": "Was there a verify hit?",
               "name": "screeningHit",
               "margin": 5,
               "bindable": "screeningHit",
               "title": "Was there a verify hit?",
               "columnWidth": 0.5,
               "width": "100",
               "labelAlign": "left",
               "itemId": "kbfmjgi",
               displayField:'Name',
               valueField:'Id',
               queryMode:'local',
               store: myHit,

          }, {
              "xtype": "combo",
              "fieldLabel": "Country Risk (Nationality)",
              "name": "countryRisk",
              "margin": 5,
              "bindable": "countryRisk",
              "title": "Country Risk (Nationality)",
              "columnWidth": 0.5,
              "width": "100",
              "labelAlign": "left",
              "itemId": "kbgajgi",
              displayField:'Name',
              valueField:'Id',
              queryMode:'local',
              store: myRisk
         }, {
             "xtype": "combo",
             "fieldLabel": "Occupation Risk",
             "name": "occupationRisk",
             "margin": 5,
             "bindable": "occupationRisk",
             "title": "Occupation Risk",
             "columnWidth": 0.5,
             "width": "100",
             "labelAlign": "left",
             "itemId": "kbaajgi",
             displayField:'Name',
             valueField:'Id',             
             queryMode:'local',
             store: myRisk
        }, {
                "xtype" : "filefield",
                "fieldLabel": "Upload evidence of verify (Screenshot from the verify portal)",
                "msgTarget" : "side",
                "allowBlank" : "false",
                "buttonOnly" : "true",
                "margin" : 5,
                "name" : "uploadFile",
                buttonConfig : {
                    "text" : "Upload",
                    "icon" : "images/cloud/upload.png",
                },
                listeners : {
                    change :"uploadFile"
                }
            }],
         "layout": "vbox",
         "autoScroll": true,
         "margin": 5,
         "columnWidth": 0.5,         
         "itemId": "nehbeki",
         "dockedItems": []
    }],
          "layout": "column",
          "autoScroll": true,
          "border": true,
          "margin": 5,
          "itemId": "gjihcpi",
          "dockedItems": [{
               "xtype": "toolbar",
               "dock": "bottom",
               "ui": "footer",
               "isToolBar": true,
               "isDockedItem": true,
               "items": [{
                    "xtype": "tbfill",
                    "itemId": "hajhegi"
               }, 
/*               {
                    "xtype": "button",
                    "name": "cancel",
                    "text": "Cancel",
                    "margin": 5,
                    "isResetButton": true,
                    "itemId": "bbkmkmi",
                    "listeners": {
                         "click": "oncancelclick"
                    }
               },*/ 
               {
                    "xtype": "button",
                    "name": "Confirm",
                    "text": "Confirm",
                    "margin": 5,
                    "itemId": "celbgji",
                    "listeners": {
                         "click": "onConfirmclick"
                    }
               }],
               "columnWidth": 0.5,
               "itemId": "lfmepni",
               "dockedItems": []
          }]
     }],
     "border": true,
     "autoScroll": false,
//     "title": "New Customer Verify",
     "margin": 5,
     "itemId": "dinfmki",
     "dockedItems": [],
     "extend": "Ext.form.Panel",
     "listeners": {
          "afterrender": "onafterrender",
          "scope": "controller"
     },
     "requires": ["Test.test.web.test.controller.test.NewCustomersVerifyController", "Test.test.shared.test.viewmodel.test.NewCustomersVerifyViewModel", "Test.test.shared.test.model.test.NewCustomersVerifyModel"],
     "viewModel": "NewCustomersVerifyViewModel",
     "controller": "NewCustomersVerifyController"
});
```

Below is my button onConfirmclick function call on NewCustomersVerifyContoller.js

```
onConfirmclick: function(me, e, eOpts) {
      var jsonData = {};
      jsonData.contactId = this.view.down('#oidgafi').getValue();
      jsonData.screeningId = this.view.down('#didgafi').getValue();
      jsonData.screeningHit = this.view.down('#kbfmjgi').getValue();
      jsonData.countryHit = this.view.down('#kbgajgi').getValue();
      jsonData.occupationHit = this.view.down('#kbaajgi').getValue();
      var scope = this.getView();
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            msg : 'Saving data...',
            progressText : 'Saving...',
            width : 300,
            wait : true,
            waitConfig : {
                interval : 200
            }
        });
      Ext.Ajax.request({              
           url: 'secure/NewCustomersVerifyServiceWS/respond',
           method: 'POST',
           sender: scope,
           jsonData: jsonData,
           me: me,
           success: function(response, scope) {
                Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                responseData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Server Response', responseData.response.message);
                win = scope.sender.up();
                win.reportViewController.queryCriteria.controller.filterData(win.searchButtonRef);
                win.close();
           },
           failure: function(response, scope) {
                Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                responseData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Server Response', responseData.response.message);
           }
      }, scope);
 }
```

Below is the error i was getting on the browser console.

> [E] Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.21 - Error
>   reportH1
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
>   H2
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;}
>   H3
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;}
>   BODY
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}
>   B
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A
>   {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px;
>   background-color: #525D76; border: none;}
>
> ## HTTP Status 400 -
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message**
>
> **description** The request sent by the client was
>   syntactically incorrect.
>
> #### Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.21

Comment: You have read and understood the error message *You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String*, I guess. Please post the json that went over the wire. I guess you will also have to show us what the Tomcat expects (i.e. how the request is parsed/the response is generated on the server).

Comment: Hi Alex, The following is my request {contactId: "86ACA66B-719E-4C04-9747-804100F64C5A", screeningHit: "1", countryHit: "0",…} contactId : "86ACA66B-719E-4C04-9747-804100F64C5A" countryHit : "0" occupationHit : "0" screeningHit : "1"

Comment: Exactly what it says,. You can see the server isn't sending back JSON, it's sending an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Error is on Ajax success or failure function. You are trying to decode invalid json which is passed from your controller (or middle layer server). You need to console the response before decode any string. 
Just add console log before Ext.decode(). and post response here. That will solve your problem.

Comment: The following is my request {contactId: "86ACA66B-719E-4C04-9747-804100F64C5A", screeningHit: "1", countryHit: "0",…}
contactId
:
"86ACA66B-719E-4C04-9747-804100F64C5A"
countryHit
:
"0"
occupationHit
:
"0"
screeningHit
:
"1"

Comment: Hi Sanket, Can you please share information as code. I was new to EXT and Ajax. Don't know how to do **console the response** the exact code and which line.

Comment: @Arun Put `console.log(response.responseText);` before the `Ext.decode` line

Comment: @Sanket I was getting the same error on the log **The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.** . Which I was previously mentioned on the post

Comment: @Arun comment out all code of success and failure function including Ext.decode(). Then put console in your code then you can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your support.

I have declared the variable **occupationRisk** as **occupationHit **.
That's the problem... Now its solved.